# Jackson register custom json serializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules, jackson-databind

This is my custom JSON Serializer and I'm trying to register it as a module. Here is what I have so far.

```
public class MaptoListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Car<?, ?>>> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Map<String, Car<?, ?>> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
             gen.writeObject(value.values());
        }
}
```

Here is my module class that I created (**Can't seem to add serializer**).

```
public class CustomModule extends SimpleModule {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9105685985325373621L;

public CustomModule() {
    super("CustomModule");
}

@Override
public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
    SimpleSerializers serializers = new SimpleSerializers();

    //THIS DOESN'T WORK . HOW DO I ADD THE SERIALIZER?
    serializers.addSerializer(HashMap.class, new MaptoListSerializer ());

    context.addSerializers(serializers);
 }
}
```

Here is how  Object mapper it used (**This works**)

```
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new CustomModule());
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue due to using `HashMap`, a raw type while this case requires generics. You can solve this by basing you custom serializer on [StdSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html) as recommended in the docs. Keep the `serialize` method as it is, but define serializer with a constructor like this:

```
class MaptoListSerializer extends StdSerializer<Map<String, Car<?, ?>>> {
    MaptoListSerializer(JavaType type) {
        super(type);
    }
```

Then to the important bit where you create an appropriate `JavaType` and pass it to this constructor:

```
MapType type = context.getTypeFactory()
    .constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, Car.class);
serializers.addSerializer(new MaptoListSerializer(type));

context.addSerializers(serializers);
```

Comment: how would you do the deserializer?

I did the same as an extended StdDeserializer.... but not sure ow to add it to Deserizlier now...

Comment: Your custom serializer produces a JSON array from the `Car` values of `Map`. You want to deserialize this into a `List<Car>` I presume ? In this case my hints: `JavaType type = context.constructCollectionType(List.class, Car.class);` and `deserializers.addDeserializer(List.class, new MaptoListDeserializer(type));`

Comment: sorry it would be ListToMapDeserializer